# lightbox2 not displaying image after clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox2

I have no idea what I am doing wrong but I am trying to use lightbox2 on a simple gallery. I have stripped the page down to nothing trying to figure out why lightbox is only giving me the overlay but not displaying the image. This is the page http://hearttoheartnc.com/store.html

Any help is greatly appreciated as I have googled this problem and can't find any solutions.

Comment: Image corrupt or truncated: http://hearttoheartnc.com/assets/img/black.jpg

Comment: Also, please excuse any messy code/way-too-large image sizes; this is a quick wireframe of a site I am doing for someone.

Comment: hows you trying? please show us your code..

Comment: What should I do? I tried using it with other images that are displaying fine on the site and it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the latest version of jquery, on your store.html file, try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```